# R How to rename variables in one tibble using another tibble serving as a dictionary

Tags: r, rename, tidyverse, tibble

I would like to change the names of a tibble using another tibble which work as a dictionary.

however, **I don't know if the order of the table's variables are the same as the dictionary's rows**.

The only thing assured is that the first variable of the names table
holds all the variable names in the data

examples:

in the simplest case (not this problem) the order of the variables is equal to the ordering of the dictionary's rows

```
cars <- as_tibble(mtcars)

wanted_names <- tribble(~names, ~new,
                        "mpg","arbitary1",
                        "cyl","arbitary2",
                        "disp","x",
                        "hp","y",
                        "drat","f",
                        "wt","sss",
                        "qsec","ffff",
                        "vs","wvegsb",
                        "am","dhyhjn",
                        "gear","scsssfsf",
                        "carb","arbitaryn")
names(cars)
```

[1] "mpg"  "cyl"  "disp" "hp"   "drat" "wt"   "qsec" "vs"   "am"   "gear" "carb"

I could just use-

`names(cars)<-wanted_names$new`

yet I cannot vouch for the order of `wanted_names` or `cars`, so it actually looks similar to this:

```
cars <- as_tibble(mtcars) %>% 
  select(wt,hp,carb,everything())

wanted_names <- tribble(~names, ~new,
                        "wt","sss",
                        "qsec","ffff",
                        "vs","wvegsb",
                        "am","dhyhjn",
                        "disp","x",
                        "hp","y",
                        "drat","f",
                        "cyl","arbitary2",
                        "gear","scsssfsf",
                        "mpg","arbitary1",
                        "carb","arbitaryn")
```

any method that could assure correct renaming will be appreciated.

Comment: You can just join your tibbles. 
`carsNew <- dplyr::left_join(cars, wanted_names, by = "names") %>% select(-names)`

Comment: thanks but the problem is that cars is in a wide format, so there is no common variable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach is to use `match`.

```
names(cars) <- wanted_names$new[match(names(cars),wanted_names$names)]
cars
#   arbitary1 arbitary2     x     y     f   sss  ffff wvegsb dhyhjn scsssfsf arbitaryn
#       <dbl>     <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>    <dbl>     <dbl>
# 1      21           6  160    110  3.9   2.62  16.5      0      1        4         4
# 2      21           6  160    110  3.9   2.88  17.0      0      1        4         4
# 3      22.8         4  108     93  3.85  2.32  18.6      1      1        4         1
# 4      21.4         6  258    110  3.08  3.22  19.4      1      0        3         1
# 5      18.7         8  360    175  3.15  3.44  17.0      0      0        3         2
# 6      18.1         6  225    105  2.76  3.46  20.2      1      0        3         1
# 7      14.3         8  360    245  3.21  3.57  15.8      0      0        3         4
# 8      24.4         4  147.    62  3.69  3.19  20        1      0        4         2
# 9      22.8         4  141.    95  3.92  3.15  22.9      1      0        4         2
#10      19.2         6  168.   123  3.92  3.44  18.3      1      0        4         4
# … with 22 more rows
```